# Found a trick to show that $f$ is linear (?)

Tags: linear-algebra

**Let $f: \mathbb R^3 \longrightarrow R^3$ be given by
$$f:\left(\begin{array}{c}{x_{1}} \\ {x_{2}} \\ {x_{3}}\end{array}\right) \longmapsto \left(\begin{array}{c}{x_{1}+x_{2}} \\ {x_{2}} \\ {x_{3}-x_{1}}\end{array}\right)$$
Prove that $f$ is linear.**

*my answer*

I could use

\begin{array}{l}{f(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})=f(\mathbf{u})+f(\mathbf{v})} \\ {f(c \mathbf{u})=c f(\mathbf{u})}\end{array}

to prove that $f $ is linear. Put I have found a trick to do this without much effort.

*Claim: $f$ is linear if the coordinates of $f(\bf u)$ are linear.*

In this case $x_1+x_2$, $x_2$ and $x_3-x_1$ are linear, therefore $f$ is linear.

Does this theorem and the belonging proof exist?

Comment: what do you mean by the linearity of the coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your $f$ in components as $f=(f_1,f_2,f_3)$. Since each of the components is linear you have:

$$f(u+v) = (f_1(u+v),f_2(u+v),f_3(u+v)) $$
$$= (f_1(u)+f_1(v),f_2(u)+f_2(v),f_3(u)+f_3(v))$$
$$ = (f_1(u), f_2(u), f_3(u)) + (f_1(v), f_2(v), f_3(v)) = f(u)+f(v)$$

similarly you can show $f(cx) = cf(x)$.

This means your $f$ is indeed linear if each of the components is linear.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proof if you know those three maps are linear, and that a sum of linear maps is linear. But the fact that this exercise was assigned suggests that you are meant to just check the axioms directly, which is only a couple lines anyway. For example,

$$f\left(c\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}\right)=f\begin{pmatrix}cx_1 \\ cx_2 \\ cx_3 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}cx_1+cx_2 \\ cx_2 \\ cx_3-cx_1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}c(x_1+x_2) \\ cx_2 \\ c(x_3-x_1) \end{pmatrix}=c\begin{pmatrix}x_1+x_2 \\ x_2 \\ x_3-x_1 \end{pmatrix}=cf\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}.$$